# python PyRanges warning message when the intersection is empty

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyranges

Dear python community,

Im trying to figure out why im getting the following warning message when I try to find the intersection between two pyrange dataframes whenever the resulting intersection is empty:

the code is the following:

```
intersection = PR1.intersect(PR2)
```

Where PR1 and PR2 are PyRange dataframes.

the error is as

*/home/dir/to/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyranges/methods/intersection.py:49: FutureWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`
scdf.loc[:, "End"] = new_ends*

I will not get this warning message if the intersection is not empty. Any idea why Im getting this? also any idea if in the future this warning message my alter my PR1?

Thank you for your time.